# Visualforce page reloads itself after actionFunction call

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction

I would like to use the component apex:actionFunction to set a variable from a custom controller but after the call, the Visualforce page reloads itself. :/

I use `return false;` on the outputLink component and the rerender attribute but it doesn't work.

This is my code :

Visualforce page :

```
<apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="setTheSource" action="{!setTheSource}">
            <apex:param name="selectedSource" value="{!$Label.Labs_Sf_Formulaire_QR_Label}" assignTo="{!selectedSource}" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>

<apex:outputLink value="#" id="contactusForm" onclick="setTheSource(); return false; showFeedbackDialog(); return false;" rendered="{!pkbCon.selectedLanguage != 'ru'}" >{!$Label.Labs_Sf_Contact_Us}</apex:outputLink>
```

Custom controller :

```
public String selectedSource {get;set;}

public PageReference setTheSource()
    {
        System.debug('SOURCE HERE!!! ' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedSource'));
        this.selectedSource = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedSource');

        return NULL;
}
```

Have you any idea for why it doesn't work please?

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using false in the rerender attribute, you should just leave is blank. Example rerender="". That has worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, Salesforce redirect me. :/

The controller method is not called when I see the debug logs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make setTheSource method void.
When you return null from an action method it's normal the VisualForce page to reload.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this matters; I use return type of PageReference in my actionmethods all the time and if I want to refresh the page, I return null.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I use a Visualforce component, a Force.com site and knowledge.

I tested my code in another organization and it works.

A Visualforce page calls a Visualforce component giving its controller.

Visualforce Page => Apex controller => Visualforce component.

Salesforce tried to redirect me to this URL : /knowledge/TOCArticleRendererPkb.apexp